# Writing foreign characters to .json file, eclipse vs jar

Tags: java, json, eclipse, utf-8, jar

Using eclipse IDE to for tests on writing data to .json and .txt files with few foreign(Chinese, Hindi) characters using Java. I could successfully write into .txt where as .json displayed ascii characters.
Code Snippet:

```
try(BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("test.json")))) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("key", "Hello, ओ ो ु ऋ 样品");
            String str = obj.toJSONString();
            System.out.println(str);
            br.write(str);
            br.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output of .txt: `{"key":"Hello, ओ ो ु ऋ 样品"}`

Output of .json: `{"key":"Hello, à¤“ à¥‹ à¥� à¤‹ æ ·å“�"}`

Have tried using `DataOutputStream` to write data. But the result is same.

On decoding, it worked to decode back as same foreign character and looks good. 
On building a jar, and running the same as .jar file doesn't give same results. Writing and Reading both were displayed in ascii. Yes, I understand in eclipse the file is saved as utf-8, which helped to compile. By the way I'm using `maven` to build the jar.

Please help me with the wayout a solution. Thanks.

Comment: I feel it depends on decoding. have you tried set decoding on your output .json?

Comment: Worried looking at the output. Haven't tried decoding yet. Let me try.

Comment: I believe he/she means _encoding_.